# jQuery Beginner Hovers, with if statements

Tags: jquery, if-statement, hover, mouseevent, mouseover

Right now, I have this code that works:

```
$( "a.tw" ).hover(function() {
$( "a.st" ).css("background-image", "url(stw.png)");  
});

$( "a.tu" ).hover(function() {
$( "a.st" ).css("background-image", "url(stu.png)");  
});

$( "a.in" ).hover(function() {
$( "a.st" ).css("background-image", "url(sin.png)");  
});
```

However, what I really want to do is have "if" statements for all of them.
If I hover over one of the above classes, I want the BG will change.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: of course if there's a more elegant way to code it with the if statements, i'd love to learn. Especially since    $( "a.st" ).css("background-image" is always targeted.

Comment: Are you not using css because the `.st` element is not inside the `hovered` element? Depending on the visual position of elements, you might still be able to do this with css.

Comment: @Joonas it looks like this:

`<a href="#" class="tw"></a>

<a href="#" class="tu"></a>

<a href="#" class="in"></a>

<a href="#" class="to"></a>

<a href="#" class="cu"></a>
<a href="#" class="st"></a>`

Comment: I should have seen that coming. For some reason I thought you had multiple `.st` elements as well. ||  You could probably do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/KN4rE/ This is relatively flexible way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Easier way is to make your background into a class if possible :

```
$('a.tw').hover(function() {
   $('a.st').toggleClass('background-stw');  
});
```

CSS

```
.background-stw
{
   background-image : url('stw.png');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("a.tw,a.tu,a.in").hover(function () {
    var $a = $(this)
    $("a.st").css("background-image", function () {
        if ($a.hasClass('tw')) {
            return "url(stw.png)";
        }
        if ($a.hasClass('tu')) {
            return "url(stu.png)";
        }
        if ($a.hasClass('in')) {
            return "url(sin.png)";
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is great. You can use `else if` statements instead of the last two `if` statements.

Comment: here's an extension, I have this code above:
`code`<link id="css_swap" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="w.css" />`code`

I have a toggle function which toggles that link between w.css and t.css

is there a way to check if it's t.css or w.css before performing the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use live() function, so it works on DOM

```
$('a').live('hover', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('tw'))
    {
        // Applay bg
    }
});
```